# Solving The Sagrada Familia Magic Square using Depth First Search in Java

Tags: java

first excuse me for my English it is not strong.

Yesterday a friend tell me about The Sagrada Familia Magic Square that is conformed by 16 numbers in a 4x4 matrix.

According to the creator "Antoni Gaudi" there are 310 possible combinations of 4 number without getting repeated that sums 33 'age at which Jesus died'.

So, i have created a java program using Depth First Search algorithm "just for practice" but i just get 88 combinations, i would like to know if there is anything wrong with my code or if making 310 combinations is not possible.

PDT:"I have searched on internet if it is not possible to make 310 combinations but without lucky".

The program has three classes Nodo, IA, Pila.

"IA is the main part of the project which centralize everything, Nodo is just a Node and Pila is for Stacking purposes"

First, I have divided the matrix 4x4 [Sagrada familia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGVnN.jpg) in position and values. Position starts at 0 and ends in 15 and each position has a specific values "wath the hastable on IA"

The program creates every possible combination of positions in a DFS way "combinations of four numbers" and then checks if they sum 33.

the value -1 is a special number that means that this position can take any number.

How does it works - tree   ('posx','posy','posw','posz')

```
                           -1,-1,-1,-1

                  0,-1,-1,-1                  1,-1,-1,-1    . . .

         0,1,-1,-1      0,2,-1,-1  . . .  1,0,-1,-1       1,2,-1,-1   . .

    0,1,2,-1     . . . . . . . .

  0,1,2,3 . . .
```

Nodo Class

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
*
* @author Vicar
*/
public class Nodo {


private int posx;
private int posy;
private int posw;
private int posz;
private int valx;
private int valy;
private int valw;
private int valz;

public Nodo (){
    posx=-1;
    posy=-1;
    posw=-1;
    posz=-1;
    valx=-1;
    valy=-1;
    valw=-1;
    valz=-1;
}

public Nodo (int posx, int posy, int posw, int posz, int valx, int valy, int valw, int valz){
    this.posx=posx;
    this.posy=posy;
    this.posw=posw;
    this.posz=posz;
    this.valx=valx;
    this.valy=valy;
    this.valw=valw;
    this.valz=valz;
}
//returns the sum
public int sumar (){
    return valx+valy+valw+valz;
}
//Returns the position of each value
public String retornarPos(){
    return posx+","+posy+","+posw+","+posz;
}
//returns the value
public String retornarVal(){
    return valx+","+valy+","+valw+","+valz;
}
//Returns the sorted position of the 4 combinations
public String retornarPosOrdenado(){
    int [] arreglo ={posx,posy,posw,posz};
    Arrays.sort(arreglo);
    return arreglo[0]+","+arreglo[1]+","+arreglo[2]+","+arreglo[3];
}

    /**
 * @return the posx
 */
public int getPosx() {
    return posx;
}

/**
 * @param posx the posx to set
 */
public void setPosx(int posx) {
    this.posx = posx;
}

/**
 * @return the posy
 */
public int getPosy() {
    return posy;
}

/**
 * @param posy the posy to set
 */
public void setPosy(int posy) {
    this.posy = posy;
}

/**
 * @return the posw
 */
public int getPosw() {
    return posw;
}

/**
 * @param posw the posw to set
 */
public void setPosw(int posw) {
    this.posw = posw;
}

/**
 * @return the posz
 */
public int getPosz() {
    return posz;
}

/**
 * @param posz the posz to set
 */
public void setPosz(int posz) {
    this.posz = posz;
}

/**
 * @return the valx
 */
public int getValx() {
    return valx;
}

/**
 * @param valx the valx to set
 */
public void setValx(int valx) {
    this.valx = valx;
}

/**
 * @return the valy
 */
public int getValy() {
    return valy;
}

/**
 * @param valy the valy to set
 */
public void setValy(int valy) {
    this.valy = valy;
}

/**
 * @return the valw
 */
public int getValw() {
    return valw;
}

/**
 * @param valw the valw to set
 */
public void setValw(int valw) {
    this.valw = valw;
}

/**
 * @return the valz
 */
public int getValz() {
    return valz;
}

/**
 * @param valz the valz to set
 */
public void setValz(int valz) {
    this.valz = valz;
}
}
```

Pila class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
*
* @author Vicar
*/
public class Pila {
private Stack <Nodo> pila;
private ArrayList<String> valor;
public Pila (){
    pila = new Stack();
    valor = new ArrayList<String>();
}

//add a Node to the stack
public void agregar(Nodo nodo){
    pila.push(nodo);
    valor.add(nodo.retornarPos());

}

//Pops a node from the stack

public Nodo sacar(){
    valor.remove(valor.indexOf(pila.peek().retornarPos()));
    return pila.pop();

}
// checks if the stack is empty
public boolean estaVacia(){
    return pila.isEmpty();
}
// checks if the stack contains an specific node
public boolean contiene(String busqueda){
    return valor.contains(busqueda);
}
}
```

IA Class

```
import java.util.*;

/**
*
* @author vicar
*/
public class IA {

Hashtable<Integer,Integer> tabla=new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();

//add the matrix 4,4 to a hastable (pos,val)
public IA(){
    tabla.put(0, 1);
    tabla.put(1, 14);
    tabla.put(2, 14);
    tabla.put(3, 4);
    tabla.put(4, 11);
    tabla.put(5, 7);
    tabla.put(6, 6);
    tabla.put(7, 9);
    tabla.put(8, 8);
    tabla.put(9, 10);
    tabla.put(10,10);
    tabla.put(11, 5);
    tabla.put(12, 13);
    tabla.put(13, 2);
    tabla.put(14, 3);
    tabla.put(15, 15);
}


//DFS
public ArrayList<String> busquedaAProfundidad(){
    Pila pila = new Pila();
    ArrayList <String> visitados = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList <Nodo> hijos = new ArrayList<Nodo>();
    ArrayList <String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();

    Nodo nodoRaiz = new Nodo();
    pila.agregar(nodoRaiz);

    //Chsck if the stack is empty
    while(!pila.estaVacia()){

        Nodo nodo = pila.sacar();
        visitados.add(nodo.retornarPos()); 
        //i get every possible children from the node
        hijos=crearHijos(nodo);
        for (int i = 0; i < hijos.size(); i++) {
            //checks that the node is not visited and the sum results in 33
            if(!visitados.contains(hijos.get(i).retornarPos()) && !pila.contiene(hijos.get(i).retornarPos())){
                    if(hijos.get(i).getPosx()!=-1 && hijos.get(i).getPosy()!=-1 && hijos.get(i).getPosw()!=-1 && hijos.get(i).getPosz()!=-1 && hijos.get(i).sumar()==33 ){

                   //this is the final result without repeted numbers
                   if(!resultado.contains(hijos.get(i).retornarPosOrdenado())){
                       resultado.add(hijos.get(i).retornarPosOrdenado());
                   }


                }
                else{

                //System.err.println("pos: "+hijos.get(i).retornarPosOrdenado());
                pila.agregar(hijos.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;

}

    // method to create children from a father node
public ArrayList<Nodo> crearHijos(Nodo padre){
    ArrayList <Nodo> hijos = new ArrayList<Nodo>();


    //positions of the father
    int x = padre.getPosx();
    int y = padre.getPosy();
    int w = padre.getPosw();
    int z = padre.getPosz();



    if (x==-1 && y==-1 && w==-1 && z==-1){
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            hijos.add(new Nodo(i,-1,-1,-1,tabla.get(i),-1,-1,-1));
        }
        return hijos;
    }
    else if(x>=0 && y==-1 && w==-1 && z==-1){
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (x != i){
                hijos.add(new Nodo(x,i,-1,-1,tabla.get(x),tabla.get(i),-1,-1));
            }
        }
    }
    else if(x>=0 && y>=0 && w==-1 && z==-1){
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (x != i && y != i){
                hijos.add(new Nodo(x,y,i,-1,tabla.get(x),tabla.get(y),tabla.get(i),-1));
            }
        }
    }
    else if(x>=0 && y>=0 && w>=0 && z==-1){
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (x != i && y != i && w !=i){
                hijos.add(new Nodo(x,y,w,i,tabla.get(x),tabla.get(y),tabla.get(w),tabla.get(i)));
            }
        }
    }

    return hijos;

}

}
```

a final class to check the result and send the output to a txt file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

/**
*
* @author vicar
*/
public class Probador {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IA run = new IA();
    ArrayList<String> resultado = run.busquedaAProfundidad();

    try {

        File archivo = new File("/tmp/gaudi.in");


        FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);



        for (String resul : resultado) {
            escribir.write(resul+"\n");

    }


        escribir.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al escribir");
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 310 refers to the number of combinations *of any size* taking elements from the matrix (without picking the same cell twice). See https://blog.sagradafamilia.org/en/divulgation/the-magic-square-the-passion-facade-keys-to-understanding-it/

> Here are the **seventeen** possible combinations of three numbers: [...]
>   With four numbers, there are **88** possible combinations that add up to
>   33; with five, there are **131**; and with six, **66**. With seven numbers,
>   there are **eight** different combinations:...

17 + 88 + 131 + 66 + 8 = 310